# Vuforia 6.0.117 0x501 error when rendering texture

Tags: android, opengl-es, vuforia

I'm trying to get Vuforia 6.0.117 working in my Android app. I'm using this specific version since its the last version supporting FrameMarkers. The detection of FrameMarkers is working fine, but when i'm trying to render a texture over the FrameMarker on my phone I get an error stating:

After operation FrameMarkers render frame got glError 0x501

My renderFrame method:

```
// Clear color and depth buffer
    GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GLES20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    // Get the state from Vuforia and mark the beginning of a rendering
    // section
    State state = Renderer.getInstance().begin();

    // Explicitly render the Video Background
    Renderer.getInstance().drawVideoBackground();

    GLES20.glEnable(GLES20.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    GLES20.glEnable(GLES20.GL_BLEND);
    GLES20.glBlendEquation(GLES20.GL_FUNC_ADD);
```

//        GLES20.glBlendFunc(GLES20.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GLES20.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
        GLES20.glBlendFunc(GLES20.GL_ONE, GLES20.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

```
    // We must detect if background reflection is active and adjust the
    // culling direction.
    // If the reflection is active, this means the post matrix has been
    // reflected as well,
    // therefore standard counter clockwise face culling will result in
    // "inside out" models.
    GLES20.glEnable(GLES20.GL_CULL_FACE);
    GLES20.glCullFace(GLES20.GL_BACK);
    if (Renderer.getInstance().getVideoBackgroundConfig().getReflection() == VIDEO_BACKGROUND_REFLECTION.VIDEO_BACKGROUND_REFLECTION_ON) {
        GLES20.glFrontFace(GLES20.GL_CW);  // Front camera
    } else {
        GLES20.glFrontFace(GLES20.GL_CCW);   // Back camera
    }

    // Did we find any trackables this frame?
    if (mActivity.isHelpVisible() || state.getNumTrackableResults() == 0) {
        // no marker scanned
        mActivity.hideInfoButton();
    } else {
        // Get the trackable:
        TrackableResult trackableResult = state.getTrackableResult(0);
        float[] modelViewMatrix = Tool.convertPose2GLMatrix(trackableResult.getPose()).getData();

        // Check the type of the trackable:
        MarkerResult markerResult = (MarkerResult) trackableResult;
        Marker marker = (Marker) markerResult.getTrackable();

        if (markerId != marker.getMarkerId()) {
            markerId = marker.getMarkerId();
            tag = DataManager.getInstance().getTagByMarkerId(markerId);
            if (tag != null) {
                texture = Texture.loadTexture(tag.getTexture());
                setupTexture(texture);
                tag.addToDB();
            }
        }

        if (tag != null) {
            String poiReference = tag.getPoiReference();
            if (!poiReference.isEmpty()) {
                mActivity.showInfoButton(poiReference);
            }

            // Select which model to draw:
            Buffer vertices = planeObject.getVertices();
            Buffer normals = planeObject.getNormals();
            Buffer indices = planeObject.getIndices();
            Buffer texCoords = planeObject.getTexCoords();
            int numIndices = planeObject.getNumObjectIndex();

            float[] modelViewProjection = new float[16];

            float scale = (float) tag.getScale();
            Matrix.scaleM(modelViewMatrix, 0, scale, scale, scale);

            Matrix.multiplyMM(modelViewProjection, 0, vuforiaAppSession.getProjectionMatrix().getData(), 0, modelViewMatrix, 0);

            GLES20.glUseProgram(shaderProgramID);

            GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(vertexHandle, 3, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, vertices);
            GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(normalHandle, 3, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, normals);
            GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(textureCoordHandle, 2, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, texCoords);

            GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(vertexHandle);
            GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(normalHandle);
            GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(textureCoordHandle);

            GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0);
            GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture.mTextureID[0]);
            GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(mvpMatrixHandle, 1, false, modelViewProjection, 0);
            GLES20.glUniform1i(texSampler2DHandle, 0);
            GLES20.glDrawElements(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, numIndices, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, indices);

            GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(vertexHandle);
            GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(normalHandle);
            GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(textureCoordHandle);

            SampleUtils.checkGLError("FrameMarkers render frame");
        }
    }

    GLES20.glDisable(GLES20.GL_DEPTH_TEST);

    Renderer.getInstance().end();

}
```

I'm loading a texture of the size 640x482 and is loading as follows:

```
public class Texture {

public int mWidth;          // The width of the texture.
public int mHeight;         // The height of the texture.
public int mChannels;       // The number of channels.
public ByteBuffer mData;    // The pixel data.
public int[] mTextureID = new int[1];
public boolean mSuccess = false;

public static Texture loadTexture(String fileName) {

    try {
        InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(fileName);
        BufferedInputStream bufferedStream = new BufferedInputStream(inputStream);

        Bitmap bitMap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bufferedStream);

        bufferedStream.close();
        inputStream.close();

        int[] data = new int[bitMap.getWidth() * bitMap.getHeight()];
        bitMap.getPixels(data, 0, bitMap.getWidth(), 0, 0, bitMap.getWidth(), bitMap.getHeight());

        return loadTextureFromIntBuffer(data, bitMap.getWidth(), bitMap.getHeight());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(Constants.DEBUG, "Failed to load texture '" + fileName + "' from APK");
        Log.i(Constants.DEBUG, e.getMessage());
        return null;
    }
}

public static Texture loadTextureFromIntBuffer(int[] data, int width, int height) {
    // Convert:
    int numPixels = width * height;
    byte[] dataBytes = new byte[numPixels * 4];

    for (int p = 0; p < numPixels; ++p) {
        int colour = data[p];
        dataBytes[p * 4] = (byte) (colour >>> 16); // R
        dataBytes[p * 4 + 1] = (byte) (colour >>> 8); // G
        dataBytes[p * 4 + 2] = (byte) colour; // B
        dataBytes[p * 4 + 3] = (byte) (colour >>> 24); // A
    }

    Texture texture = new Texture();
    texture.mWidth = width;
    texture.mHeight = height;
    texture.mChannels = 4;

    texture.mData = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(dataBytes.length).order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    int rowSize = texture.mWidth * texture.mChannels;
    for (int r = 0; r < texture.mHeight; r++) {
        texture.mData.put(dataBytes, rowSize * (texture.mHeight - 1 - r), rowSize);
    }

    texture.mData.rewind();

    texture.mSuccess = true;

    return texture;
}
```

}

Anybody got an idea why i'm getting this error and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot go over your entire code right now, and even if I could I'm not sure it would help. You first need to narrow down the problem, so I will first give you the method to do that, and I hope it will serve you in other cases as well.

You managed to find out that there was an error - but you are checking it only at the end of the rendering function. What you need to do is to place the `checkGLError` call in several places inside the rendering code (print a different text message), until you can pin-point the exact line after which the error first appears. Then, if you cannot understand the problem, comment here what is the problematic line and I will try to help.

### UPDATE:

After looking at the shader code, following your report that `normalHandle` is -1, I got to the following conclusions:

The error, which indicates the variable `vertexNormal` cannot be found in the shader, may be due to the fact that this variable is probably optimized out during shader compilation, since it is not really required.

Explanation: in the vertex shader (CUBE_MESH_VERTEX_SHADER), vertexNormal is assigned to a varying called `normal` (variable that is passed to the fragment shader). In the fragment shader, this varying is declared but not used.
Therefore, you can actually delete the variables vertexNormal and normal from the shader, and you can delete all usages of 'normalHandle' in your code.

This should eliminate the error.

Comment: I've added multiple checkGLError calls to see where the 0x501 is coming from. It seems to come from the normal variable, these are the three statements which return a GLError  

```GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(normalHandle, 3, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, normals);```

```GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(normalHandle);```

```GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(normalHandle);```

Don't really know what is going wrong there...

Comment: It probably means that this variable, normalHandle, is not 'connected' to the proper variable in the shader. If you have a variable representing the normal in the shader, you need to make sure its handle is set. Look at where you assign the shader vars handles - should be something like: normalHandle= glGetAttribLocation(shaderProgramID, "nameOfNormalVar");

Comment: I've found the part where the normalHandle is set:
```normalHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(shaderProgramID, "vertexNormal");```

So the shaderProgramID is set as follows:

```shaderProgramID = SampleUtils.createProgramFromShaderSrc(
                CubeShaders.CUBE_MESH_VERTEX_SHADER,
                CubeShaders.CUBE_MESH_FRAGMENT_SHADER);```

I've posted the function createProgramFromShaderSrc on Pastebin:
https://pastebin.com/qjxCMZVi

Comment: The code of the shaders is what't missing here - createProgramFromShaderSrc  loades the shader, but we need to look at ubeShaders.CUBE_MESH_VERTEX_SHADER and  CubeShaders.CUBE_MESH_FRAGMENT_SHADER

Comment: Two questions: #1). after the line "Buffer normals = planeObject.getNormals();", do 'normals' have a value (the buffer is not empty)?. #2) You said the error from the gl statements involving 'normalHandle' - is the error starting from the first line: GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(normalHandle...  ?

Comment: #1: The planeObject.getNormals() returns ```java.nio.DirectByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=48 cap=48]```

#2: The error is coming from that line yes : ```GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(normalHandle, 3, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, normals);```

When creating the normalHandle with ```normalHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(shaderProgramID, "vertexNormal");``` it returns -1

Comment: If it returns -1 it means it cannot find a variable called "vertexNormal" in this shader. If you say that the line " GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(vertexHandle,..." does not create an error, try to track the creation and assignment of 'vertexHandle', which seems to be working well, to your problematic 'normalHandle'

Comment: The vertexHandle is created here : ```vertexHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(shaderProgramID, "vertexPosition");```

That's it no reference somewhere else in the code. Is the vertexPosition maybe created by Vuforia itself?

Comment: No, is vertexPosition is created in CUBE_MESH_VERTEX_SHADER, and 'vertexHandle' is the pointer to it. normalHandle is supposed to be a pointer to vertexNormal, but the pointer assignment (via normalHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(shaderProgramID, "vertexNormal")) fails. You need to track down and see why it cannot find vertexNormal.

Comment: I've tried to change the CUBE_MESH_VERTEX_SHADER to the new shader provided by Vuforia (latest version) but that also didn't work. I can't seem to figure out why it isn't finding the vertexNormal in the shader :(

Comment: I've updated my answer with my final observation details.

Comment: thx for the answer! I removed the vertexNormal and normal from the shaders and removed all the normalHandle code from my FrameMarkerRenderer. When I run the app no errors occur but the object isn't drawn (this my indicate an error somewhere else in my code). But the errors are gone! thx man

Comment: Glad to help. Feel free to accept the answer if it really helped you. BTW, if you have no errors now but the object is not displayed, I would recommend checking the matrix - position or scaling. Good luck!

Comment: I checked out the matrix position and scaling they seem to be correct. I see the object displayed for a short time like a flicker. You have any suggestions?

Comment: As you probably already tried, you have to figure out what changes and cause it to disappear. Although you said you have checked the matrix, I would make sure it stays the same along the entire check - meaning, make sure it looks ok even after the object disappears. This is still the prime suspect to me since: you know the target is detected, you know your object can be drawn, and I assume you have no weird conditions that change along the way and preventing the object from being displayed.